# Angular Error: error:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

This is one angular error Url. open up.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:21:412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:21:53)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:21:296%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:35:185%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:35:33)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Jb%20(http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:38:269)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:18:3)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20rc%20(http:%2F%2F120.24.153.50%2Fcb_hrms%2Fviews%2FcloudStaticPage%2Fleave%2Fresource%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js:18:316

Comment: Did you forget to append an array after your module declaration -- `angular.module('app', [])`?

Answer (score 0):

You app module is not able to find all the dependencies.

It is possible you have injected any component or other dependency and forgot to include the file or code for it under main Module.

To check this you have to figure out which dependecncy is not loading.

- you may go to last working version and compare what new dependencies (components,service etc) you have injected in app module and than see if its availble in brower under source .

I hope this will help.

Top Causes :

- Wrong Spelling or not correctly injected
- dependency angular code is not inculded under app hence while compliling it fails to map it under app.